# Any Angular app ceated crashes. Node reinstall and reboot didn't work

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Yesterday I tried to move an angular project in to a different folder. Subsequently I've tried to use ng serve to start the app, but it failed. Out of curiosity I created a new project and tried to run ng serve, but surprisingly it also failed with the same error

Both projects failed with the same error. Since then I've also tried reinstalling node and tried a reboot. None of this has fixed the error

This is the debug log output:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/joltx/node/node-v14.15.3-linux-x64/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/joltx/node/latest/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.9
3 info using node@v14.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0~prestart: teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0~start: teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0~start: PATH: /home/joltx/node/node-v14.15.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/.bin:/home/joltx/.vscode-server/bin/ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523/bin:/u00/app/oracle/local/tvdperl-Linux-x86-64-02.04.00-05.08.04/bin:/u00/app/oracle/mdb_jumpserver/local/bin:/u00/app/oracle/mdb_jumpserver/bin:/u00/app/oracle/mdbtools/bin:/u00/app/oracle/mdbtools/local/bin:/u00/app/oracle/product/18.0.0.0/client_1/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/u00/app/oracle/local/dba/bin:/u00/app/oracle/local/tvdusr/bin:/u00/app/oracle/local/tvdas/bin:/home/joltx/.vscode-server/bin/ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523/bin:/opt/quest/bin:/opt/symantec:/opt/six/midrange/uvscan:/opt/six/midrange/rkhunter:/usr/openv/netbackup/bin:/opt/ctmadmin:/opt/ctmagent:/opt/Sterling:/opt/uc4/executor/bin:/home/joltx/node/latest/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/u00/app/oracle/product/18.0.0.0/client_1/OPatch
9 verbose lifecycle teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0~start: CWD: /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend
10 silly lifecycle teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'ng serve' ]
11 info lifecycle teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 verbose stack Error: teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/joltx/node/node-v14.15.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
13 verbose pkgid teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0
14 verbose cwd /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend
15 verbose Linux 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64
16 verbose argv "/home/joltx/node/node-v14.15.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/joltx/node/latest/bin/npm" "run" "start"
17 verbose node v14.15.3
18 verbose npm  v6.14.9
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error syscall spawn
21 error file sh
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is the /tmp/ng-OO2Ha4/angular-errors.log output:

```
[error] Error: NGCC failed.
    at NgccProcessor.process (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:119:19)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:590:31
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:55:30)
    at createWebpack (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack-dev-server/index.js:21:36)
    at Object.runWebpackDevServer (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack-dev-server/index.js:47:12)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js:166:32)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:47:27)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

This is the output as seen in the console:

```
joltx@localhost:~/projects/dba_portal/frontend> npm run start

> teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0 start /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend
> ng serve

WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
case.
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Error: Error on worker #2: Error: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, copyfile '/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/keycodes.js' -> '/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/keycodes.js'
    at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1991:3)
    at NodeJSFileSystem.copyFile (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/file_system/src/node_js_file_system.js:68:16)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/writing/new_entry_point_file_writer.js:85:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at NewEntryPointFileWriter.copyBundle (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/writing/new_entry_point_file_writer.js:79:49)
    at NewEntryPointFileWriter.writeBundle (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/writing/new_entry_point_file_writer.js:46:18)
    at writeBundle (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/create_compile_function.js:58:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:195:27)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:55:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:293:57)
    at step (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:140:27)
    at Object.next (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:121:57)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:287:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "/tmp/ng-OO2Ha4/angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the teamhp2-frontend@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/joltx/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T15_33_32_462Z-debug.log
joltx@localhost:~/projects/dba_portal/frontend> (node:6045) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:832:20)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:703:19)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:51:21
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.sendMessageToMaster (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:46:16)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/worker.js:104:66
    at step (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:140:27)
    at Object.throw (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:121:57)
    at rejected (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:112:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6045) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6045) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:6031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:832:20)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:703:19)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:51:21
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.sendMessageToMaster (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:46:16)
    at /home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/worker.js:104:66
    at step (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:140:27)
    at Object.throw (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:121:57)
    at rejected (/home/joltx/projects/dba_portal/frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:112:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6031) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the folder structure of the project. I have no idea why this is happening, as this very project ran perfectly prior to the move of the frontend folder.

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: update the paths in angular.json

Comment: I can't find any paths that wouldn't work in the new folder. None of them reference the absolute path. I've already looked at it. Do you reckon I should change the project name too?

Comment: then please `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm install` and `ng serve`

Comment: I've tried that already. As well as removing the package-lock.json. Neither worked after reinstalling the modules.

Comment: somewhere in the source code must be an absolute URL, search after the old location in the whole project.

Comment: Now this is really weird. After deleting node_modules multiple times, it still keeps the same paths from the old folder before I moved the project. I deleted the node_modules folder along with the package-lock.json.

Comment: make a break, an hour, then search again ;)

Comment: so I've tried literally everything. Nothing worked. I found out that this problem even affects newly created projects. So even projects that have nothing to do with my old project now fail with the same error. I've reinstalled node, and this issue persists. At this point I don't even know what is happening

Comment: I‘ll try it on my local machine and give you a feedback

Answer (score 0):

So I cannot reproduce this problem after following the steps below:

```sh
ng --version

  @angular-devkit/architect    0.1100.5 (cli-only)
  @angular-devkit/core         11.0.5 (cli-only)
  @angular-devkit/schematics   11.0.5 (cli-only)
  @schematics/angular          11.0.5 (cli-only)
  @schematics/update           0.1100.5 (cli-only)

ng new anEmptyNgProject

  ? Do you want to enforce stricter type checking ..? Yes
  ? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
  ? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? SCSS
  CREATE ....
  ✔ Packages installed successfully.
      Successfully initialized git.

cd anEmptyNgProject
npm start

  Compiling ....
  ✔ Compiled successfully.

^C
cd ..
mv anEmptyNgProject anEmptyNgProject2
cd anEmptyNgProject2/
npm start

  Compiling .... 
  ✔ Compiled successfully.
```

It seems so that a specific library has been falsely linked anywhere in the configuration or an import process.

Comment: If it is a v10 related problem (please follow the steps above with Angular10 before to be sure), I would like to post an issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues